# How to invoke inline click handler immediately using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I write a click hander like this;

```
$("#button1").click(function(evntData)
{
  alert("button1 clicked.");
});
```

to invoke it immediately I do like this;

```
$("#button1").click(function(evntData)
{
  alert("button1 clicked.");
}(null));
```

in this way it is called on start up and work fine. but later when button is clicked this event handler is not called. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) click event:

```
$("#button1").click(function(evntData) {
    alert("button1 clicked.");
}).trigger('click');
```

Another way is to actually call the function and provide the same function reference as event handler:

```
function onClick(evntData) {
    alert("button1 clicked.");
}

$("#button1").click(onClick);

onClick(); // you can pass object parameter evntData if needed
```

Comment: as in my case I attached the single click handler on multiple buttons. these buttons are in a list so I did $("ul button").click(handle). the first solution calls the function as many times as total number of buttons. how to make it to call only once?

Comment: You want to simulate click for only one button? Which one? You need to take a button you want and call click handler on specific one. For example on the first button from the collection: `$("ul button").click(handle).first().trigger('click')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.click()` after binding the click event to trigger click :

```
$("#button1").click(function(evntData)
{
  alert("button1 clicked.");
}).click(); //or .trigger('click')
```